Arrange 9pcs of 3x3 matrices into a 9x9 matrix in specific order
The main problem is I have to arrange the matrices:
matrix1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
matrix2 = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
matrix3 = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
matrix4 = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]])
matrix5 = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]])
matrix6 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
matrix7 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
matrix8 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
matrix9 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])

into a 9x9 matrix where the
row_sums == [9, 4, 9, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 4]) and
column_sums == [5, 4, 5, 7, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4]) and
diagonal_sum1 == 6 and diagonal_sum2 == 6)

all matrix have to be used and for only once and can not be rotated.
visual
on paper I know what it should be but cant make work in python.
I tried with brute force, random placing them till it find the correct solution (with IF to check the sums) but the program just got frozen.
Tried to arrange them by place 1,2,3 and check but cant figure out how to not use what was used, tires new, and in the next section use which failed previously.
is there a way to solve this in python?

You can solve this (and much larger problems) with binary integer linear programming using scipy.optimize.milp. Here is an example of a slightly different problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78017047/how-to-rearrange-numbers-in-a-4x4-grid-to-all-sum-up-to-0/78018082#78018082. Consider posting a solution once you've solved it.

You can brute force it; there are only 9! arrangements, and that's not so many.  You're asking for some sophisticated deductive logic to realize that the top row needs 6, 7, and 9, and the 7 needs to be rightmost because it's the only non-symmetric column.  I don't think you can deduce that.

yeah, tried brute force and it looks like i was just impatient with the running code.

@user12471498 could you please undo your edit that "self-destructs" the question? It would be helpful for others to see the original question, especially since someone answered it

Brute force version (without any optimizations):
from itertools import permutations

import numpy as np

matrices = [
    matrix1,
    matrix2,
    matrix3,
    matrix4,
    matrix5,
    matrix6,
    matrix7,
    matrix8,
    matrix9,
]

for c in permutations(matrices, 9):
    r1 = np.r_[c[0], c[1], c[2]]
    r2 = np.r_[c[3], c[4], c[5]]
    r3 = np.r_[c[6], c[7], c[8]]

    f = np.c_[r1, r2, r3]

    row_sums = f.sum(axis=1)
    if np.allclose(row_sums, [9, 4, 9, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 4]):
        col_sums = f.sum(axis=0)
        if np.allclose(col_sums, [5, 4, 5, 7, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4]):
            if f.diagonal().sum() == 6 and np.fliplr(f).diagonal().sum() == 6:
                print("Solution:")
                print(f)
                break

Prints (this takes ~13 seconds on my AMD 5700x):
Solution:
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]]

real    0m13,802s
user    0m0,008s
sys     0m0,008s


Yes that worked. for me it took about 45-60 secs... but still way more elegant than my attempt, thanks.

@RichárdKovács One quick optimization would be to move matrix7,matrix8,matrix9 as first matrices in matrices list (because first three matrices must be these). This cuts search time considerably.
